# What is the correct usage of extends Function with Parameters and ReturnType

Tags: typescript, redux, reselect

I'm trying to create my own memoization function for reselect. I had to redefine `Parameters` and `ReturnType` to accept `extends Function` (bug?). The signature for `myMemoize` is correct however the inner function signature isn't compiling.

```
import { createSelectorCreator } from "reselect";

type Parameters<T extends Function> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
type ReturnType<T extends Function> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : any;

function myMemoize<F extends Function>(func: F): F {
  // ...
  return function(...args: Parameters<F>): ReturnType<F> {
    //...
    return func.apply(null, args)
  }
}

export const createMyMemoizeSelector = createSelectorCreator(myMemoize)
```

The error:

```
error TS2322: Type '(...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F>' is not assignable to type 'F'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your new function is not really of the same type as the original. The original might have extra properties, that you do not forward to the return function.

You can just skip the return type, and also `Parameters` and `ReturnType` (both of which are defined so don't redefine them), are not really necessary for a full typed version :

```
function myMemoize<P extends any[], R>(func: (...a:P)=> R): (...a:P)=> R {
  // ...
  return function(...args: P): R {
    //...
    return func.apply(null, args)
  }
}
```

Not sure how this interacts with `createSelectorCreator` though.

Comment: Okay so perhaps createSelectorCreator signature is the problem? 

createSelectorCreator(memoize: <F>(func: F) => F)

Answer (score 0):

> `Type '(...args: Parameters<F>) => ReturnType<F>' is not assignable to type 'F'`

Fundamentally `...args` implies any number of arguments, whereas F might take a very specific count.

## Fix

You don't need `Prameters` / `ReturnType` for your use case as `(func: F): F` covers external type safety and you don't need internal type safety. Here is the simpler way:

```
function myMemoize<F extends Function>(func: F): F {
  // ...
  return function(...args: any[]): any {
    //...
    return func.apply(null, args)
  }
}
```

Comment: error TS2322: Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'F'.

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer doesn't reflect OP's specific implementation as closely as others, if you're looking for a simple typed memoize function, this works:

```
export function memoized<A, B>(f: (a: A) => B): (a: A) => B {
  const cache = new Map()
  return a => {
    if (!cache.has(a)) {
      const b = f(a)
      cache.set(a, b)
      return b
    }
    return cache.get(a)
  }
}
```